# RG flow from a UV scale invariant field theory to a gapped phase in the IR

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, scale-invariance

On the section 3 of http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.2921 the authors consider the RG flow from a scale invariant field theory in the UV to a gapped theory in the IR. The theory is couple to a background metric $g_{\mu\nu}$.

They state that since the theory in the IR is gapped the low energy effective action is a local functional of the background metric.

How can I prove this statement? They say in a footnote that their main argument could be extended to the case when the IR is a CFT. In that case I wouldn't have a gapped theory in the IR, right?! So what is the importance of the IR being in a gapped phase?